# Text inline with centered image

Tags: html, css, alignment

Having some difficulty with this one. I haven't learned HTML but I'm getting the hang of it.

On my website, I have a logo centered at the top of the site. I want to add some text to the left side of the website INLINE with the image without moving the image position.

```
             LOGO
             LOGO
             LOGO
Text here    LOGO
|------------------------------|  (Page width)
```

The text CANNOT be above or below the logo line because it messes up the rest of the page.

EDIT: I decided to remove "What I have now" because it is confusing out of context.

So how would you tackle this scenerio?

Comment: Apologies, but I am unfamiliar with that. I simply cut out the portion of code I'm working with because I know some people don't like when people rewrite things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but is this what you want? :) http://jsfiddle.net/ex65xetj/

```
<div class="wide">
    <img src="path/to/image"></img>
    <span>Text here</span>
</div>
```

Simply wrap the logo section in a wrapper.

Make it position relative(so children absolute positioning is relative to this element and not the page).

Then position absolute the text.

Make the left and bottom position value of the text 0, so it sticks to the bottom left.

Comment: What you jsfiddle shows is exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately my lack of experience with HTML/CSS (the past few days) is leaving me a bit lost when it comes to implementing it into what I have now. It appears that my CSS file uses a different syntax? It uses XenForo syntax I believe

Comment: Let me try some things based on your code :)

Comment: XenForo? A syntax? Can't find on web.

Comment: Wikied it. Apparently, XenForo is a php library?

Comment: Here is a snapshot. it says at the bottom, you may use XenForo syntax http://i.gyazo.com/b55cd3d81633ff76839ff7a8ee5832c7.png

Comment: I saw the image, CSS does **not** come with different syntaxes, you can use it :)

Comment: Cool! Then let me try to work something out :)

Comment: And if they parse CSS with a plugged in syntax extension, using vanilla CSS will be absolutely fine.

Comment: Sorry for this, but I do not understand how to implement your CSS into the file I have now. Is it possible for you to help me with that? :) My HTML: http://pastebin.com/bMHDzFfa My CSS: http://pastebin.com/TqQBkbyK

Comment: The CSS formatting just looks so different to me in terms of the "function names"?  .wide etc?

Comment: @mc360pro CSS doesn't have functions since it's a **markup language**, that's just a class placeholder, just change it to your liking

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="logo-div">
    <img src="" alt="logo"/>
    <div class="text-block">Your text goes here</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.logo-div{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:40px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
}
.text-block{
    top:70px;
    left:190px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raghuchandrasorab/jy9n4hp2/

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for since the text is on the line under the logo.

Comment: people can not spoon feed you till that level.. change the left, and top values in css to get it aligned the way you want and add howmuch ever images you want in html!

Comment: This has nothing to do with spoonfeeding. What you showed is something I already know how to do. I need the text to be INLINE with the logo, not under it.

Comment: Cant explain you more than this all the best! Thank you!

Comment: Appreciate your effort. The jsfiddle that Daniel shows demonsrates what Im after. Notice how the text is on the same line as the logo.